# Determining if public proxies are anonymous

Tags: php, python, http, proxy

I would like to set up on my server a service that would determine if a proxy server I scraped off the net is anonymous or not. What I need is just a uri, from which the server would return the request exactly as it was received, and then to check if my public IP is in the response string(in HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR for example).

Has anyone has ever done this before?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not write a simple PHP script and check this for yourself?

```
<?php
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}
?>
```

Save it as `headers.php` and call it in your browser via the proxy server. All the request headers seen by the server will be echo'd on screen.

Comment: Even simpler, phpinfo() will also print all request headers.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to Gaurav I got it done with this simple php script (`getallheaders()` need PECL):

```
<?php
$headers = array();
foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key, 'HTTP_') === 0) {
        $headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', strtolower(substr($key, 5)))))] = $value;
        echo $value;
    }
}
?>
```

If anyone ever needs this..